# Issue with adding users to roles user asp.net role provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, membership-provider, roleprovider

I have a database set up using entity framework code first. I have all the asp.net user role management stuff set up already. I have one user I have been using for awhile and it is working fine, and I just added another user and I can log in fine. I want to set up roles (which i have named two: Admin and Users). I get the roles set up fine, but when I try to add my user to a role I get the follow error (I am using the webadmin tool):

```
An error was encountered. Please return to the previous page and try again. 

The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: The user 'userName' was 
not found. at System.Web.Administration.WebAdminPage.CallWebAdminHelperMethod(Boolean 
isMembership, String methodName, Object[] parameters, Type[] paramTypes) at 
ASP.security_roles_managesinglerole_aspx.EnabledChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) at 
System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox.OnCheckedChanged(EventArgs e) at 
System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox.RaisePostDataChangedEvent() at 
System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox.System.Web.UI.IPostBackDataHandler.RaisePostDataChangedEvent()
at System.Web.UI.Page.RaiseChangedEvents() at 
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean 
includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

I read a couple of questions on this and tried to update the web config but it did not work. Here is my current web.config setting:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <remove name="DefaultRoleProvider"/>
    <add connectionStringName="NerdlyContext" applicationName="/"
      name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

If I use SSMS I can see both the User and Role tables populated correctly. And I have the UsersInRoles table, but it is empty.

This is an asp.net MVC4 application using .net 4.0.

here is the full, sanitized web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
<remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
<add name="LocalSqlServer" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:sql2k804.discountasp.net;Initial Catalog=boobs;User ID=boobs;Password=boobs;" />
</connectionStrings>
<appSettings>
<add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
<add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
<httpRuntime />
<machineKey />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="NerdlyThings" name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/" name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Also when I change it to use the old SQL provider i just get a different error saying it doesn't like my schema version??

Comment: I've done a quick lookup on the net and most accepted answers seem to centre around web.config configuration as you suggest - could you include more of your web config especially centred around connection strings (minus private details obviously) and then the sections to do with providers and membership please?

Comment: @bUKaneer I updated with the full config

Comment: Can you reproduce the error(s) with a fresh File - New - Project? Or is it just in your current app?

Comment: That was actually what I was going to do next. Very possible I did something somewhere along the line that made this issue come up. I will try tonight.